# find (two) words next to each other in texts with python with proximity operators. excalable solution

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, proximity

I am relatively beginner in python and I am looking for a solution for the following Problem.

I have to "scan" texts looking for concepts.

A concept looks like this:  (electrical 3d car)

I have to look for appearences of the word "car" where in a proximity of 3 words ('3d') there is another being 'electrical' (for instance electrical conventional car, electrical propulsed car, electrical driven autonomous car etc)

I know that you can work with a text as if it would be a list of words and punctuations.

I thought about the following solution:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    concept=['motor','3d','car']
    concept_appearences=0 ## counters
    concept_positions=[]
    concept_list=[]
    word1 = concept[0]
    word2 = concept[2]
    separator=concept[1]

    distance=[int(s) for s in separator if s.isdigit()]
    distance=int(distance[0])

    distanceright=distance
    if 'd' in separator: distanceleft=distance
    if 'w' in separator: distanceleft=0

    for line in fp:
      ## look for the concepts in every line which is like a paragraph

      for index,word in enumerate(line.split()):
           if word.upper()==word1.upper():
                ## i found the first concept-word
                for i in range(index-distanceleft,index+distanceright,1):
                if line.split()[i]==word2:
                    ##print('thline.split()[i],word2)
                    print('i found the concept in postion', i )
                    start,end=i,index
                    if index<i:start,end=index,i 
                         print('check:',line.split()[start:end+1])
                         concept_appearences +=1
                         concept_list.append(line.split()[start:end+1])
                         concept_positions.append(start)
  print('the concept appeared {} times'.format(concept_appearences))
  print('in positoins',concept_positions)
  print('list of concepts',concept_list)
```

Note: Not yet implemented is the case where there is a point between both words which will exclude the hit from being a concept. (like: blah blah electrical. The car of my aunt blah blah.... that should not be a hit for obvious reasons)

Probably not a super-pythonic code, but it works so far.
The questions here are.

First:
This seems to me to be a quite common problem. Is there any library specific for that? 
I don't even know the "technical" name for such a thing beyond than "proximity operators" 
Note: I read quite a bit about NLTK (a NL library) but did not really find a solution for that.

Second:
Any idea how to make this code scalable? meaning this (electrical 3d car) could in itself become a concept within a concept, when looking for instance for (electrical 3d car) in the surroundings of "gasoline" being gasoline not more than 10 words away:
((electrical 3d car) 10w gasoline)

Third:
If there is no library for such a thing, any comment on speed is welcome, I have to look for thousands of concepts within a 100 pages text.

Thanks a lot.

Re-edit adding an input and outputfile as asked by @Mathieu thx.

INPUT TEXT:
Referring to FIGS. 1 to 3, an electrical car 1 comprises bodywork 2, pairs of ground engaging wheels 3, 4 front and rear, an electric motor 5 driving the front wheels 3 through a suitable transmission (not shown) and electrical battery sets 6A, 6B for supplying electrical power to the motor 5. Suitable control gear (not shown) adapted for operation by the car driver serves to control operation of the electric motor 5 and hence motion of the car 1. An old electrical driven car found in the garage was painted yellow instead of blue.

output:
the concept appeared 2 times
in positoins [7, 82]
list [['electrical', 'car'], ['electrical', 'driven', 'car']]

Comment: Can you add a sample of I/O as well ?

Comment: @Mathieu, I added I/O in the core text of the question. Thx.

Comment: After investigating in stack overflow I suspect that a tool to use here is n-grams of words in NLTK. but its just a hint